# Как компьютеры узнают IP адреса друг друга в P2P системе?

Tags: p2p

Можно отправлять на все доступные адреса в интернете запросы с надеждой получить ответ. Но ведь в одной локальной сети может быть несколько компьютеров, которые скрыты за одним внешним ip. Так как же получить доступ ко всем находящимся онлайн пользователям?

Comment: Никак, только какие-нибудь промежуточные серверы использовать

Comment: Для начала изучите что такое маршрутизация и домены.

Comment: @andreymal Я прочитал про это. Но ведь если промежуточный сервер упадет, то и все p2p сеть упадет. Тогда о какой устойчивости можно говорить?